# Signal SIGABRT in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, xcode4.3

I have table in which i would like to tap on the cell and it takes me to another table. 
I got this error while running in Xcode 4.3.2 :

```
 return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([RanchForecastTouchAppDelegate class]));

 Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT
```

I saw alot of answer related this error in this forum but it didn't work, it's the reason that I asked question again.

My code is:
CreateViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CreateViewController : UIViewController <
UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
NSArray *tableData;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tableData;
@end
```

CreateViewController.m

```
#import "CreateViewController.h"

@implementation CreateViewController
@synthesize tableData;


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Johan", @"Paul",@"George",@"Ringo", nil];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

#pragma mark - TableView Data Source methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
return [tableData count];

}


  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

}
cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}


 @end
```

Error message on console:

`[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68ab4d0`

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68ab4d0'`

Edit:

```
#import "RanchForecastTouchViewController.h"

@interface RanchForecastTouchViewController ()

@end

@implementation RanchForecastTouchViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
} else {
    return YES;
}
}

 @end
```

RanchForecastTouchViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RanchForecastTouchViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your user interface connection, It would be for some wrong connections!

Answer (score 0):

you added semicolons at the end of the line

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{ ...
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{....
}
```

just remove them

Comment: That's unlikely to be the issue - Obj-C allows this.

Comment: @Chakalaka problem again -->>  [UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6854510

Comment: return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([RanchForecastTouchAppDelegate class]));

 Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT

Comment: do you have more ViewControllers?

Comment: is RanchForecastTouchViewController a delegate for a tableview? if yes so you need to implement numberOfRowsInSection... too